# PHP CLI script not timing out

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

We have a node js script that runs a command to execute the following command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/www/441.php {"id":"325241"}
```

This script does a lot of things, however it does not seem to respect the time limit. The first line of this file is:

`set_time_limit(1800);`

Yet if we check what processes are running on the server (`ps -aux | grep php`) we will see a lot of these commands that have been open since last week.

Any ideas on how we can clean this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_time_limit` only has meaning to the php part of the program. If you had a query on a database that takes 5h to finish, those 5h are not counted by php, so they fall out of scope of the `set_time_limit` limitation. Having said that, it seems weird that a php process is still running after a week, if it is not calling another program that runs forever (which, in this case, the `set_time_limit` neither affects that calling).

Also, what does the `-q` flag? I can't find it on `man php` nor `php --help` nor in [php's command line options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php).

Comment: -q is quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem is with another piece of software that the PHP script calls, and that is hanging not the PHP itself which is why set_time_limit won't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following comment on the PHP user guide for max_execution_time

> Keep in mind that for CLI SAPI
>   max_execution_time is hardcoded to 0.
>   So it seems to be changed by ini_set
>   or set_time_limit but it isn't,
>   actually. The only references I've
>   found to this strange decision are
>   deep in bugtracker
>   (http://bugs.php.net/37306) and in
>   php.ini (comments for
>   'max_execution_time' directive).

So it would seem that there's a bug in the CLI module that means max_execution_time is effectively ignored.

The commenter mentioned a page in the bug tracker about this at http://bugs.php.net/37306 but the tracker seems to be down.

Answer (score 0):

If you start the script in nodejs, why not kill it there too, after 1800s?

```
var pid = startPHPProcess();

setTimeout(function() {
    killPHPProcess(pid);
}, 1800);
```